# Prevent PHPExcel to calculate values when writing to file

Tags: php, special-characters, phpexcel

When writing my data in an Excel file with class PHPExcel.

**This is happening when the writer works, not when adding data to the cells `$this->sheet->setCellValue()`**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Adressen!AF20955 -> Formula Error: Unexpected operator '>'' in \Cell.php:300 Stack trace: 
#0 \PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(754): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()
#1 \PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(373): PHPExcel_Worksheet->calculateColumnWidths()
#2 \PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(80): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->_writeCols(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter), Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet))
#3 \PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php(304): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->writeWorksheet(Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), Array, false)
#4 \excel.php(131): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('...')
#5 \excel. in \PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 300
```

I never use the function `PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()` writing to my Excel but only `$this->sheet->setCellValue('A1', $value)`.

I don't need to calculate any formula in my Excel file. Just exporting DB2 data to this file.

It is obviously possible that `$value` contains formula characters like `= + - > <` (as the cell `AF20955` did causing the fatal error with `>`) but this should not be interpreted as formula but only as part of string. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: what exactly is in `$value` when you get this error?

Comment: No idea, it is a database field, very hard to find out what it is exactly.... If it's needed I can search for the value

Comment: then try/catch the write call and have the catch spit out whatever `$value` was at that point.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean?

Comment: `try { $this->sheet->setCellValue('A1', $value) } catch (exception $e) { die("setCell barfed with value: $value"); }`

Comment: As written in my question: This is happening when the writer works, not when adding data to the cells `$this->sheet->setCellValue()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The PHPExcel calculation engine is called by default when you save, but you can tell the writer not to apply it by calling

```
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
```

before the call to save

---

When you set a cell value with a call to `setCellValue()` or similar, PHPExcel will attempt to identify the datatype and set it appropriately internally (in exactly the same way as MS Excel) using the value binder. Cells that contain a `=` as the first character will be considered as formulae by this.

If you want to ensure that they are treated as strings instead of formulae, then the easiest approach is to use `setCellValueExplicit()` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Using `setCellValueExplicit()` is working well. I also tried using only `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);` but the error persist!

Comment: If you're using autowidth columns, then PHPExcel needs to execute any formulae, even if setPreCalculateFormulas is set to false, in order to calculate the column width because that's based on the actual formatted, displayed value for the cell

Comment: Thanks man! That solved all my problems while using a xls model file.

Comment: If you are using LaravelExcel, this might help: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/pull/708